# Question about TS2322 error in Svelte Component

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm studying Svelte with TypeScript.

I faced `TS23` error in this code.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Test1 from './Test1.svelte';
    import Test2 from './Test2.svelte';

    let components = [
        { name: 'Test1', component: Test1 },
        { name: 'Test2', component: Test2 }
    ];
    let selected;
</script>

{#each components as { name, component } (name)}
    <label><input type="radio" value={component} bind:group={selected} />{name}</label>
{/each}

<svelte:component this={selected} />
```

> Type 'typeof ComponentTest1__SvelteComponent_' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[]'.
>
> Type 'typeof ComponentTest1__SvelteComponent_' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more. ts(2322)

This error occurred in the `value` attribute of the `input` tag.

How should I handle this? I really do not have an idea of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript says that the `value` attribute of the radio input can only be a string, number, or array of strings (`string | number | string[]`). Assuming `name` will be unique, you can use name as the value instead. This will require some more work to map the name back to a component, but it's pretty minimal.

This example binds the radio inputs to `selectedName` instead, and sets up a reactive statement to find the associated component whenever `selectedName` is updated.

```svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import Test1 from './Test1.svelte';
    import Test2 from './Test2.svelte';

    let components = [
        { name: 'Test1', component: Test1 },
        { name: 'Test2', component: Test2 }
    ];
    let selectedName;

    $: selected = components.find((c) => c.name === selectedName);
</script>

{selectedName}
{#each components as { name, component } (name)}
    <label
        ><input type="radio" value={name} bind:group={selectedName} />{name}</label
    >
{/each}

{#if selected}
    <svelte:component this={selected.component} />
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there any way to use svelte's component as the value of the input element?